# Pandas: vertical look up with two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, vlookup

I have a dataframe `df1` of coordinate values like this:

```
    lat         lon         E               N
0   48.010258   -6.156909   90089.518711    -201738.245555
1   48.021648   -6.105887   93961.324059    -200676.766517
2   48.033028   -6.054801   97836.321204    -199614.270439
... ...         ...         ...             ...
```

and another dataframe `df2` that associates a climatic value to each *(lat, lon)* pair:

```
    lat         lon        val
0   48.010258   -6.156909  17.11
1   48.021648   -6.105887  22.23
2   48.033028   -6.054801  39.86
... ...         ...        ...
```

I want to create a new column, `df1['corr_pos']`, where each row is given the index of `df2` corresponding to the *(lat, lon)* pair in `df1`. It is like using *VLOOKUP* in Excel, but using two values to identify the correct index instead of using only one. The two values are the coordinate pair.

The output would be:

```
    lat         lon         E               N               corr_pos
0   48.010258   -6.156909   90089.518711    -201738.245555  0
1   48.021648   -6.105887   93961.324059    -200676.766517  3
2   48.033028   -6.054801   97836.321204    -199614.270439  8
... ...         ...         ...             ...             ...
```

The dataframes `df1` and `df2` **do not** have the same order. **How could I implement this in pandas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to create a new column from `index`:

```
print (df2)
          lat       lon    val
7   48.010258 -6.156909  17.11
10  48.021648 -6.105887  22.23
12  48.033028 -6.054801  39.86
df = pd.merge(df1, 
              df2.reset_index().drop('val', axis=1).rename(columns={'index':'corr_pos'}), 
              on=['lat','lon'], 
              how='left')
print (df)
         lat       lon             E              N  corr_pos
0  48.010258 -6.156909  90089.518711 -201738.245555         7
1  48.021648 -6.105887  93961.324059 -200676.766517        10
2  48.033028 -6.054801  97836.321204 -199614.270439        12
```

If `df2` has many columns, it is better to use subset as merge will delete them:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, 
              df2.reset_index()[['lat','lon', 'index']].rename(columns={'index':'corr_pos'}),
              on=['lat','lon'], 
              how='left')
print (df)
         lat       lon             E              N  corr_pos
0  48.010258 -6.156909  90089.518711 -201738.245555         7
1  48.021648 -6.105887  93961.324059 -200676.766517        10
2  48.033028 -6.054801  97836.321204 -199614.270439        12
```

Comment: What if I want to add the `corr_pos` column to `df1`, instead of creating a new dataframe? Of course I don't want to lose the correspondences.

Comment: Hmmm, there is problem you need join by `2 columns`, so cannot use [map solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291908/excel-vlookup-equivalent-in-pandas/38291973#38291973). I have no idea it  is possible without `merge`, maybe `join` - all methods return new dataframe..

Comment: But I can create a new `df` and then use `map` to add the new column to `df1`.

Comment: Yes, but map need one column which is mapped to another values. If check [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40239323/2901002) there is only one column in `on` parameter, so `map` can be used. But if have more as 1 joined columns `on=['val1','val2',...]` then `map` solution is impossible.

Comment: On second thoughts this doesn't work. It creates a `corr_pos_x` and `corr_pos_y` that I do not want.

Comment: Ok, so solution does not work? You get `corr_pos_x` and `corr_pos_y` if in first and second dataframe is same column `corr_pos`. In sample is not this column. What is your code? How is modified my solution?